# Why doesn't Python3 "re" work in Jupyter?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I've got some Python3 code for finding words, possibly with imbedded #'s, -'s, apostrophes, or some international characters, in English text:

```
>>> import re
>>> exp
"((?:[\\w#éüöêåo]+[-’'])*[\\w#éüöêåo]+)"
>>> line
'William Shakespea#e was an Englis# poet, playwright a#d'
>>> re.findall( exp, line )
['William', 'Shakespea#e', 'was', 'an', 'Englis#', 'poet', 'playwright','a#d']
```

As shown, it works as intended in the Python interpreter, but returns `None` when the same code is run in a Jupyter notebook.  How come?  Perhaps it's got something to do with character encoding?

Comment: Please add the _exact_ line of code you use to create the contents of the "exp" variable above, in both environments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with `re`.  In the surrounding code, I was saying:

```
text = []
...
line = reader.readline()
text = text.extend( re.findall( regexp, line )
```

I didn't realize that String.extend works by side-effect, returning `None`.  RTFM.